# Visual Studio 2017 docker container with LocalDB

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a dev PC that is running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 and Docker for Windows 18.06. I have an asp.net project project that I've been debugging locally using a Docker linux container through Visual Studio 2017 and things have been working fine. Now I added asp.net identity to the project and when I go to register a new user I get this error:

> PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this
>   platform.

Okay, I get it, I can't run LocalDB in a Linux container. If I switch Docker to run Windows containers I get the error:

> Your Docker server host is configured for 'Windows', however your
>   project targets 'Linux'

which also makes sense. How can I switch my project to use Windows containers? This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 50823
EXPOSE 44345

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestProject/TestProject.csproj", "TestProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestProject/TestProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestProject"
RUN dotnet build "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.dll"]
```

In my Container.targets file I changed

```
`Condition="'$(DockerTargetOS)' == 'Linux'"`
```

to

```
'Condition="'$(DockerTargetOS)' == 'Windows'"
```

How can I switch my project from linux containers to windows containers so I can use LocalDB?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that at all, since LocalDB is for development only, so you are unlikely to run in nano and server core based image. And even then, LocalDB can only be connected via localhost iirc, so you wouldn't be able to connect from other images to it. Why not just use the sqlserver linux image instead?

Comment: Thanks @Tseng I thought something like this might be the case.